Can't configure location of images in Jekyll blog
Have just set up a jekyll blog and can't configure it to show images. Will mostly upload R markdown output. Not github hosted if that makes any difference.
The test file "Testing_2" shows without any image and I get this error in the server window:
[2024-11-30 13:17:35] ERROR `/staRt/2024/11/29/assets/images/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png' not found.

My folder structure is:

The test file content:
---
  layout: post
  title: "Testing 2"
  date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
  output:
    md_document:
      variant: gfm 
      preserve_yaml: true
  knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
    rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                      encoding = encoding,
                      output_file = file.path(paste0("~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/R/blog/staRt/_posts/",
                                                  Sys.Date(),
                                                  '-',
                                                  substr(basename(inputFile), 1, nchar(basename(inputFile)) - 4),
                                                  '.md'
                                                   )
                                              )
                      )
    })
---

baseDir <- "~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/R/blog/staRt/"
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                      base.dir = baseDir, 
                      base.url = "/")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "assets/images/") #default
knitr::render_jekyll()

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=hp)) + 
    geom_point(color = "firebrick", size = 4)

The _config.yml file is:
#Build settings
theme: minima
#theme: jekyll-theme-minimal
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
include:
  - assets
  - /assets/images
assets:
  dirname: assets
  baseurl: /assets/
  sources:
    - assets

The error at the very top suggests the server expects the images to be in the same folder as the post itself:
/YYYY/MM/DD/post/assets/images.
How can I configure it to find the images? Thank you all.

I have worked on this today and found a temporary fix. The *.md file created by R Studio and placed in /_posts will be rendered in /_site/YYYY/MM/DD as an *html and is looking for the image in assets/images/.... I prepended ../../.. in the file to the image location and now the rendered blog will find the image. This is an inelegant, brute-force solution and a post that will have many images will be a pain to edit. Is there a systematic way to configure it so I don't need to manually edit? Thanks y'all.
